# How can I put a slider bar in Viro React ARScene?

Tags: react-native, viro-react

I want to put a slider bar in my AR project with ViroReact.But I cant do it with my proposal.I need some help.
This is my code that I try to put two views in a screne.But It will give me the Error

> exception thrown while executing ui block unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance

I don't know how to do this.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={localStyles.outer} >
        <View style={localStyles.inner} >
          <ViroARScene onTrackingUpdated={this._onInitialized} >
            <ViroFlexView style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }} width={1} height={0.8} materials="hud_text_bg" position={[-1.5, 0, 0]} onClick={this._resetScene}>
            </ViroFlexView>
            <ViroQuad
              rotation={[-90, 0, 0]}
              position={[1, 3, -5]}
              width={10.0} height={10.0}
              arShadowReceiver={true}
              ignoreEventHandling={true} />

            <ViroButton
              source={require("./res/1.jpg")}
              position={[1, 3, -5]}
              height={2}
              width={3} />
            <ViroText text={this.state.text} scale={[.5, .5, .5]} position={[0, 0, -1]} style={styles.helloWorldTextStyle} />
            <ViroBox position={[0, -.5, -1]} scale={[.3, .3, .1]} materials={["grid"]} animation={{ name: "rotate", run: true, loop: true }} />
            <ViroAmbientLight color={"#aaaaaa"} />
            <ViroSpotLight innerAngle={5} outerAngle={90} direction={[0, -1, -.2]}
              position={[0, 3, 1]} color="#ffffff" castsShadow={true} />
            <Viro3DObject
              source={require('./res/emoji_smile/emoji_smile.vrx')}
              resources={[require('./res/emoji_smile/emoji_smile_diffuse.png'),
              require('./res/emoji_smile/emoji_smile_normal.png'),
              require('./res/emoji_smile/emoji_smile_specular.png')]}
              position={[-.5, .5, -1]}
              scale={[.2, .2, .2]}
              type="VRX" />
            <ViroNode position={[0, -1, 0]} dragType="FixedToWorld" onDrag={() => { }} >
              <Viro3DObject
                source={require('./res/emoji_smile/emoji_smile.vrx')}
                resources={[require('./res/emoji_smile/emoji_smile_diffuse.png'),
                require('./res/emoji_smile/emoji_smile_normal.png'),
                require('./res/emoji_smile/emoji_smile_specular.png')]}
                position={[-.5, .5, -1]}
                scale={[.2, .2, .2]}
                type="VRX" />
            </ViroNode>
          </ViroARScene>
        </View>

        <View style={tempstyles.container}>
          <Slider 
            maximumValue={100}
            minimumValue={0}
            minimumTrackTintColor="#307ecc"
            maximumTrackTintColor="#000000"
            step={1} 
            value={this.state.sliderValue}
            onValueChange={(sliderValue) => this.setState({ sliderValue })}>
          </Slider>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
    }
```